# How to add multiple scenarios in single feature file using jira -xray

Tags: jira

I need to write Cucumber Gherkin tests in jira x-ray, i wrote one scenario and imported the same in my framework but i  want to know if there is any way to write multiple scenario in one file in jira and import it as single feature file? (if anyone can provide the answer with an example that would be really helpful)